# Is it possible to programmatically change a setting in the Android Wear app?

Tags: android, wear-os

In an Android Wear app there's a boolean setting of 'Mute Connected Phone', I am wondering if there's a way to find the value of the setting and send an intent to the app to change this setting?

How would I go about finding the intent and bundle to send?

Answer (score 0):

It won't let me comment, but have you tried accessing AudioManager through your wear or mobile app?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setMode%28int%29

Comment: Yeah you can't comment bizarrely if you don't have enough cred on the sight. I've started looking at this option after poking around the wear apk. The main issue is that the Android Wear app doesn't just set the ringer to silent it actually disables the ringer showing that it's been done so via Android Wear. Setting to silent isn't useful as it causes the watch to do the same so it potentially have to be done at a lower level.